# OCaml Mascot can't find modules from .mli files

Tags: ocaml

Given the following source files:

```
(* /tmp/src/A.mli *)
val f : B.t -> B.t
```

---

```
(* /tmp/src/A.ml *)
let f (x : B.t) = x
```

---

```
(* /tmp/src/B.mli *)
type t
```

---

```
(* /tmp/src/B.ml *)
type t = int
```

I tried running the [mascot](http://mascot.x9c.fr/examples.html) code checker but it can't bind modules referenced from `.mli` files despite the `-I` flag.  It resolves bindings from `.ml` files just fine.

`$ mascot.native -config mascot.cfg -I /tmp/src /tmp/src/{A,B}.{ml,mli} -html /tmp/out`
**`File "/tmp/src/A.mli", line 2, characters 8-11:`**
**`Error: Unbound module B`**
`loading configuration files...`
`configuring checks...`
`analyzing dependencies...`
`running checks...`
`reporting to "/tmp/out" with output "html"...`

It resolves bindings from `.ml` files just fine.

```
$ mascot.native -config mascot.cfg -I /tmp/src /tmp/src/{A,B}.ml -html /tmp/out
loading configuration files...
configuring checks...
analyzing dependencies...
running checks...
reporting to "/tmp/out" with output "html"...
```

I can't find anything in the [manual](http://mascot.x9c.fr/distrib/mascot.pdf) which explains *files-to-analyze* but I believe Mascot is supposed to be run on interface files because the [examples](http://mascot.x9c.fr/examples.html) page includes examples of documentation problems:

> ```
> (** Module descriptoion. *)
>
> type t
> (* This one is not actually documented
>    (bare comment instead of ocamldoc one). *)
> ```

and interface checks don't seem to be run when I only supply source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit the same problem, and could make Mascot find module `B` only by compiling its interface file *and* having `B.cmi` in current directory, for example:

```
cd /tmp/src
ocamlc B.mli
mascot.native -config mascot.cfg {A,B}.{ml,mli} -html /tmp/out.html
```

It seems that there is no command-line option for telling Mascot where to look for `.mli`/`.cmi` files; the `-I` flag does not work for this, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: So if I use `ocamlbuild` then I should run mascot from the `_build` directory?

Comment: Certainly.  By the way, I think this is a limitation of Mascot.